# VBA PublishObjects. Add character formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I found the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff519602%28v=office.11%29.aspx) about putting excel cells into an email using the RangetoHTML function in VBA. It works like a charm, but now I’m facing a Problem.

If there are Umlaut (e.g.: ü, ä, ö) in the cells the result in the email shows strange symbols (e.g.: Ã¤, â€¦).

I looked up the written temp.htm file. On the first view of this file, it seems the umlaute are correctly written, but after looking through the file with an hex editor i found that the written symbols are not correct.
The function which writes the file is: PublishObjects.Add

So I hope someone can help me with this.

Edit: Added a [testfile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4407520/VBAEmailSendTest.xls). Word and Office is needed.
Select the table and run the procedure SendMail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always have problems with vba and foreign chars and the web.

**EDIT:**

Because you can't separate the cell values from the html the function below will unfortunately not work in this situation. BUT:

if you Save a copy of the document with western European windows encoding it will work.
(See comments below).

To be able to do that you press "Save As" and there is a dropdown on the left side of the save button (Tools) which will give you a dialog where you can change the encoding.
[image: Change Encoding]
The image has ben lifted from technet and always save web.. is not necessary.

**EOF EDIT:**

This is a function I have used, Unfortunately can't remember who I got it from, But its from the olden days of vba and classic asp
Put your email cell formula into this function and it should work because all the letters are html encoded. Its slow and makes a bad overhead. But it will work.

```
Function HtmlEncode(ByVal inText As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sEnc As Integer
    Dim repl As String

    HtmlEncode = inText

    For i = Len(HtmlEncode) To 1 Step -1
        sEnc = Asc(Mid$(HtmlEncode, i, 1))
        Select Case sEnc
            Case 32
                repl = "&nbsp;"
            Case 34
                repl = "&quot;"
            Case 38
                repl = "&amp;"
            Case 60
                repl = "&lt;"
            Case 62
                repl = "&gt;"
            Case 32 To 127
               'Numbers
            Case Else
                repl = "&#" & CStr(sEnc) & ";" 'Encode it all
        End Select
        If Len(repl) Then
            HtmlEncode = Left$(HtmlEncode, i - 1) & repl & Mid$(HtmlEncode, i + 1)
            repl = ""
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply; unfortunate this doesn't solve my problem. I added an test excel file to the original post.

Comment: The funny thing is the german Letters work on my machine which is english with swedish local. Verify that the publish ends up with the correct charset in the temp file (debug.print RangetoHTML). My one gets <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

Comment: My one getting:
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
This seems incorrect. So how can i change this?

Comment: Ok I managed to get your document to behave as your document did.
THis could be hard to explan as your Excel is in German and Mine is in Swedish... But lets try:

SaveAs -> and left hand side of Save there is a arrow down. Which has webalternatives. There you have a tab called Encoding and there you choose western european(Windows) And then you open the new docment and the encoding works... (Atleast I got the same behavior as you when changing it to UTF8)

Comment: OMG; thanks for that it worked!
Not shure if this is the final (best) solution; but for me its totaly fine!

Comment: Perfect I Edit the answer so you can tag it as aswered for others, And  if you find a better solution because this can brake easily please update your question or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is 10 years old but its still the first hit when searching for PublishObjects endoding issues. The answer above seems to work for some but I wanted an automated solution in vba. This sub works for me.

```
Public Sub convertCharset(sFile1Path As String, sFile2Path As String, lFile1Charset As Long, lFile2Charset As Long, Optional blnCreateFile As Boolean = True)
' Purpose: Used to convert charset of textfiles from 1 charset to another.
' Args:
'   - sFile1Path corresponds to full path (string) to file to read from.
'   - sFile2Path corresponds to full path (string) to file to write to.
'       If sFile1Path = sFile2Path then original file will be overwritten with the new charset.
'   - lFile1Charset actual charset of file to read from.
'   - lFile2Charset desired charset of file to write to.
'       Charset values can be any of the values possible for the TextStream.OpenTextFile method.
'       See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method
'   blnCreateFile = True means new file can be created at sFile2Path if file doesn't already exist
On Error GoTo err_handler
Const ForReading As Long = 1
Const ForWriting As Long = 2
Dim fso As Object
Dim txtStreamRead As Object, txtStreamWrite As Object
Dim sFileContent As String

    ' Read original file -> string (sFileContent) with specified charset (lFile1Charset)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txtStreamRead = fso.OpenTextFile(sFile1Path, iomode:=ForReading, Format:=lFile1Charset)
    sFileContent = txtStreamRead.ReadAll()
    txtStreamRead.Close
    
    ' Write string (sFileContent) to file with specified charset (lFile2Charset)
    Set txtStreamWrite = fso.OpenTextFile(sFile2Path, iomode:=ForWriting, Create:=blnCreateFile, Format:=lFile2Charset)
    txtStreamWrite.Write sFileContent
    txtStreamWrite.Close

exit_handler:
    Set txtStreamRead = Nothing
    Set txtStreamWrite = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & ERRMSG
    Resume exit_handler
End Sub
```

You can call this sub with another sub like this:

```
Private Sub convertHTMLFileCharset()
Const TristateTrue As Long = -1 ' Unicode
Const TristateFalse As Long = 0 ' ASCII
Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\path\to\my\output.html"

    convertCharset FILE_PATH, FILE_PATH, TristateFalse, TristateTrue

End Sub
```

In this example output.html created by a publishobject, initially with ASCII encoding will be converted to Unicode encoding. I hope this helps somebody else!